# How do I generate a .cpp file from source code?

Tags: c, compilation

I'm starting with C programming, and have written a program and am ready to compile.  I've heard that mingw is a good choice, but the documentation for using it starts with a .cpp file and then turns that into a .exe.  What I currently have is just the pure source (i.e. just text commands), how do I turn that into a .cpp?  Thanks.

Comment: A `.cpp` file is a text file.

Comment: This is a good question from someone who is new to programming.

Answer (score 1):

A cpp file is a C++ source file. Many tools (compilers, editors, etc.) can work with .c files or .cpp files.

A source file refers to the actual code you write. You know, stuff like

```
int main() {
   printf("Hello, world!");
   return 0;
}
```

That would be source code. 4 lines of it. So generally, you can't *generate* it. You have to *write* it. It sort of sounds like you wrote a .c file and are getting confused because you're using a tool whose example uses a .cpp file.

- If the tool works with both C and C++, then use it with the .c file.
- If it only works with C++...  then you'll have to use something else.

Comment: Thanks.  I can try it with a .c and see if that works, but that still leaves the question: Having written the source code (and knowing which headers I want to include), how do I turn it into a .c file?

Comment: You can probably just compile it anyway gcc -o out xyz.txt

Answer (score -1):

If you have written code in a file like "xyz.txt" then simply rename it to "xyz.c".  Also, you can take a file named like  "xyz.c" create a copy of it and rename that copy to "xyz.cpp" and then modify "xyz.cpp" so that it can be compiled as C++ code.

In either case the "xyz.c" when compiled becomes "xyz.exe" and "xyz.cpp" will also become an "xyz.exe" load module, but not the same as the one generated from C code.

If you want load modules for a program written in C and the same program written in C++ then you will have to give them different names, like: "xyz.c" and "abd.cpp".

Hope this helps, and welcome to our world of programming!

Comment: -1 for renaming a .c file into a .cpp file. While this sort of works in practice, there really isn't any situation where it makes sense to do.

Comment: @djechlin, sure it does.  If you have a program written in C and you want to convert it to C++.  First, rename it to *.cpp and then change the C code to be C++ code (initially not a big task).  Please take back your -1.

Comment: Why would you want to convert it to C++ in the first place, if it's a C file?

Comment: @djechlin, because that appeared to be what part of this question was about.  But, why not?  If I have some C code but want to use objects/classes and maybe run it as a Visual C++ program, then I'll start with what I know...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_of_C_and_C%2B%2B#Constructs_that_behave_differently_in_C_and_C.2B.2B because of this sort of issue

Comment: And Visual C++ can run C files to my knowledge.

Comment: @djechlin, yes, but it looks at the suffix to determine if it is a C program or C++ (.cpp) code.

Comment: @djechlin, per wiki at the SAME page: `While C and C++ maintain a large degree of source compatibility,...`  So, if necessary start with .C code and get it to work as .cpp code.